# Only initialise masonry if script is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

In my wordpress script I use conditional statements to only enqueue the [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) script on certain pages. I also have a global javascript section that loads on all pages that included the script to activate the masonry functionality:

```
$container.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.img-container',
  gutter: ".gutter-sizer"
});
```

This works fine when the main masonry script is loaded on the page but throws an `undefined is not a function` error if it isn't loaded. How do I check to see if masonry is loaded before executing the above code? I assume this would apply to most jQuery plugins and other js scripts in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($.fn.masonry) {
    //...
}
```

However I really dislike this kind of conditonnals. You should also make sure that the scripts using the library only gets loaded when really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Masonry [defines a global](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/masonry.js#L27) so you can simply do:

```
if (window.Masonry) {
  // Masonry has been loaded
}
```